# Handling Gridview.RowEdit

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, webforms

Quick one:
I've created
`public event GridViewEditEventHandler invGridEdit {}`.
Can I put code in this event to allow my end user to edit the DB entry, or do I need to point this to a new method for editing?

Edit: It's probably obvious that this is the first time I've looked at events. My apologies if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In general you have to register your own methods on specific events:

> When you create a GridViewEditEventHandler delegate, you identify the
>   method that will handle the event. To associate the event with your
>   event handler, add an instance of the delegate to the event. The event
>   handler is called whenever the event occurs, unless you remove the
>   delegate. For more information about event-handler delegates, see
>   Events and Delegates.

In your case:

```
gridview.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(myEditHandler);
```

Registered methods must have the signature your handler expects. In your case it's the delegate

```
public delegate void GridViewEditEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    GridViewEditEventArgs e
)
```

So the method `myEditHandler` looks like

```
void myEditHandler(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
```

To access the firing gridview, perform a cast on `sender`:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
```

Your method is now called, if the event `RowEditing` is fired. This is the case, when:

> The RowEditing event is raised when an Edit button (a button with its
>   CommandName property set to "Edit") is clicked, but before the
>   GridView control enters edit mode. This allows you to provide an
>   event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as
>   canceling the edit operation, whenever this event occurs.

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Is this a similar pattern to what happens automatically when I double-click an object in design view? In other words, is the event that I created redundant, and I need to use something based on your examples to point that "firing" at the method? Sorry, this is a bit new to me.

Comment: Yes, if you select the gridview in design mode, you can watch out all events. If you double click on `RowEditing` event, my example is similar (except the resulting method name). Try it out and analyze the auto-generated code :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is for any code you want to run to set up the editing on the grid.

From here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

**The RowEditing event is raised when an Edit button** (a button with its CommandName property set to "Edit") **is clicked, but before the GridView control enters edit mode**. This allows you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as canceling the edit operation, whenever this event occurs.
When you create a GridViewEditEventHandler delegate, you identify the method that will handle the event. To associate the event with your event handler, add an instance of the delegate to the event. The event handler is called whenever the event occurs, unless you remove the delegate. For more information about event-handler delegates, see Events and Delegates.